# kill -9 + disable messages (standard output) from kill command

Tags: linux, ksh

I wrote the following script which enables timeout of 20 seconds if grep can not find the relevant string in the file.

The script works well, but the output from the script is like this:

```
./test: line 11: 30039: Killed
```

1. how to disable this message from the kill command?
2. how to tell kill command to ignore if process not exist?

THX
Yael

```
#!/bin/ksh  
( sleep 20 ; [[ ! -z ` ps -ef | grep "qsRw -m1" | awk '{print $2}' ` ]] && kill -9  2>/dev/null ` ps -ef | grep "qsRw -m1" | awk '{print $2}' `   ; sleep 1 ) &
RESULT=$! 
print "the proccess:"$RESULT
grep -qsRw -m1 "monitohhhhhhhr" /var
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
print "kill "$RESULT
  kill -9 $RESULT
fi
print "ENDED"


./test

the proccess:30038
./test: line 11: 30039: Killed
kill 3003
```

Answer (score 5):

`kill -9 $RESULT &> /dev/null`

This will send `stdout` and `stderr` to /dev/null.

Comment: you miss the 1> or 2> and those also not work
please other advice?

Comment: &> redirects both stdout and stderr, so it won't output anything when the process doesn't exist or when it killed a process. The code in the question only redirects stderr for `kill`, so this answer is the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

you'd better look at `timeout` command

```
man timeout

NAME
       timeout - run a command with a time limit

SYNOPSIS
       timeout [OPTION] NUMBER[SUFFIX] COMMAND [ARG]...
       timeout [OPTION]

DESCRIPTION
       Start  COMMAND,  and  kill  it if still running after NUMBER seconds.  SUFFIX may be `s' for
       seconds (the default), `m' for minutes, `h' for hours or `d' for days.
```

Comment: sorry I cant use the timeout
and I cant to install because the linux is not my system

Comment: then you should redirect STDERR of your `grep` command to `/dev/null`, try to add `2>` or `&>`, but to "grep" command, not to "kill"

Comment: you can also check solution from here http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/106960-redirecting-stderr-file-within-bash-script.html

Comment: `ps -ef | grep "qsRw -m1" 2> /dev/null | awk '{print $2}' 2> /dev/null`

Comment: not grep ,
I need to ignore messeges from kill command not grep

Comment: not grep , I need to ignore messeges from kill command not grep

Comment: you're wrong. **`kill` command does not output any messages**. you can check this by running one long command in one terminal, and `kill`-ing it from a second terminal. you'll see 'killed' message on first terminal. `kill` not outputs anything.

Answer (score 2):

Messages are printed by your shell, not by the killed process.

Try runnning the proccess to be killed in an another shell, encapsulating command being killed like this:

```
sh -c 'command_to_be_inettrupted&'
```

The idea is to make the shell instance exit earlier than the process it started. You may also need to "nohup" your command, but that was unnecessary on my system.

For example:

```
sh -c 'sleep 10&' ; sleep 1; killall sleep
```

This code won't produce any output, despite first sleep instance being killed.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Just put everything in another shell.
You might also remove parenthesis.

Comment: I also do that and its not work????????????????????

su - c 'sleep 20 ; [[ ! -z ` ps -ef | grep "qsRw -m1" | awk '{print $2}' ` ]] &&  kill -9   ` ps -ef | grep "qsRw -m1" | awk '{print $2}' `   ; sleep 1' &

Comment: You've misunderstood my idea. Code you've just shown is the interrupting one. I propose to encapsulate the one being interrupted.
A part where qsRw program is started.

Comment: su -c 'qsRw -m1'; sleep 1;
killall qsRw

Answer (score 1):

I think this message comes from job control. Try turning it off with set +m
if that doesn't work under ksh, try the script with #!/bin/bash

Answer (score 0):

Programming in C:

```
/* Kill process without printing 'Killed' or 'Terminated' message. */
kill(pid, SIGINT);
```

or

```
execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", "kill -SIGINT `pidof <your command>` >/dev/null 2>&1", (char *)NULL);
```

killpid.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
/*
    $ gcc -W -Wall -O3 -std=c99 -pedantic -o killpid killpid.c
*/
#define LEN     10

int main()
{
    char line[LEN] = {0};
    FILE *cmd = popen("pidof <your command>", "r");

    fgets(line, LEN, cmd);
    pid_t pid = strtoul(line, NULL, 10);
    printf("pid: %ld\n", pid);

    /* Kill process without printing 'Killed' or 'Terminated' message.*/
    kill(pid, SIGINT);
    pclose(cmd);

    return 0;
}
```

By kill command:

```
$ kill -SIGINT `ps -ef | grep <your command> | awk '{print $2}'` >/dev/null 2>&1
```

or

```
$ kill -SIGINT `pidof <your command>`
```